# What is a best way to add scheduler to Solr?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, scheduled-tasks

I have custom data import handler. Currently schedulers running code is in the Inform(SolrCore core) method (handler implements SolrCoreAware). But I don't think it's good that request handler knows about schedulers. I don't want to use code on client side (eg. using solrj). I need to have one jar file which user will just add to SOLR classpath, register handler and that's all.

Is there any better common way to add scheduler to a SOLR server?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [solr-data-import-scheduler](http://code.google.com/p/solr-data-import-scheduler/). Although I haven't used it personally, I know of people who have done, and they seem to be happy with it.